# Android studio source code for canary builds

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

Is there a place where Google publishes source codes for canary builds of Android studio? I can see tags for various versions in [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+refs), but the most recent version there is the stable `4.0` version, where I would need a developer snapshot of the current `4.2` version currently being developed.

Answer (score 0):

Think you might have went through this. If not, please check this out

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/studio.md
```

Build Source Code:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/source.md
```